# CollectionViewSource Edit and Add Mode are not stable

Tags: wpf, collectionviewsource

I'm using **CollectionViewSource** and EntityFramework in my WPF project, and whenever user insert or edit a record, and want to save it, I will find it like this

```
(MyCVS.View as ListCollectionView).IsAddingNew
```

Or

```
(MyCVS.View as ListCollectionView).IsEditingItem
```

But sometimes user is in a **Edit** or **Insert** mode but those property are **false**
I want to know when and how those properties change to false.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

`IsAddingNew` and `IsEditingItem` are only `true` when you are in the middle of an add or edit transaction, which you start by calling [`AddNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.addnew%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`EditItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.edititem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) respectively.

If neither you nor the framework code behind your views call these methods then you are only going to get `false` values out of the properties.

Comment: Hi, I Do AddNew and EditItem; but If I press Tab and pass all controls in window, it's no longer True; I don't why